# How to apply collection view cell xib into collection view and add as subview in view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have create custom xib for collectionViewCell and custom collectionView. I would like to include the collectionView into view controller. When i do that nothing happen.

Below is the code in tableView to call collectionViewCell xib and load in init

```
 -(void)loadView
{
     _collectionView.dataSource = self;
     [_collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"PhotoCollection" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell"];   
}
```

Below is the code in viewController to load the collectionView xib

```
PhotoCollectionTableView *photoCollection = [[PhotoCollectionTableView alloc]init];
    [_headerView addSubview:photoCollection];
```

Anyone can help to solve this issue.